# Animated Models in XNA

Tags: xna-4.0, models, maya

I've been using XNA for 2D games for awhile, and I am just learning 3D now. I have a question, which seems like it should be fairly basic. As I understand it, I make a model in Maya (or whatever) and have some animations in it (walk, jump, etc.). How do I take that model, and put it in my game, and have it run the animation to walk? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the XNA code samples:
http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model